# Where do Darkness and Megumin live?

Tags: konosuba

In the beginning of season 1, we see Kazuma and Aqua in the stables quite often.  However, after Darkness and Megumin join the party, we don't see them in the stables, except for some shots in the ending credits.

Where do Darkness and Megumin live?

> Eventually, when they all move in the house, they live together.  But up until then, we don't see any "at home" activities of Darkness and Megumin like we do for Kazuma and Aqua.

Answer (score 5):

Within the anime, there has been no mention of where Darkness and Megumin lived prior to obtaining the mansion (not that I recall). However, in the KonoSuba manga, Darkness and Megumin both had slept in the stables as illustrated:

[image]

That's probably the most evidence I could get.

Answer (score -3):

Really the way that Kono Suba is set up, its basically this really bad DnD campaign that someone thought was a good idea to catalogue as a novel/light novel. IF that is true, then Aqua and Kazuma were the first two players to start the game. then on, two other friends join in the form of Darkness and Megumin, and the rest is history.

Its also very likely, Darkness has money saved up. (enough to lodge, but not enough to pay off the debts they rack up later into the series) and Megumin has the same situation. But I still think the writer only makes the characters relevant as they come up, and decided not to worry about the details before they became relevant.

Edit: Given the amount of evidence that presented in the Manga and Anime, it is likely that when they appeared in Axel Town, they recently arrived. Given how famished Megumin is, she probably only arrived after her journey, and thus could not establish somewhere to lodge, and needed to find a quick source of income.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ***Where do Darkness and Megumin live?***

Comment: likely in the tavern cause they have/had money. But really, does it matter?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't matter to you, but that doesn't mean to disrespect the question. Also, Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a discussion site. We strive for objective answer that can be backed up by sources/references, not pure speculation/opinion answer. As of currently written, the only relevant part of the answer is "*Its also very likely, Darkness has money saved up. (enough to lodge, but not enough to pay off the debts they rack up later into the series) and Megumin has the same situation.*", which might be true, but need to be backed up by official references.

Comment: But.... we are discussing an art form/ form of media... when none of us are the original creator.... and the only information that is ever given is within the story.... and only information that is pertinent to the story. I understand that Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, but when the creator hasn't been asked this question, and given a thorough explanation, there is nothing to do than just speculate.

Comment: @LouisCarmichael So, that would be a valid answer. "There is no canon explanation, only speculation". With a tad of elaboration, that would most likely be a well received answer as well.